# How to update the Hibernate Entity Record when only few fields of entity obj are modified and remaining fields should not be null

Tags: java, hibernate

is there any other different solution for this code.
for every pojo class we have to check that modified data coming from browser and we will store only modified data into the database.

see below billingTax  obj is coming from browser which is updated data
and billingtaxDbObject obj is retrieved from database and we will check with if condition whether updated data is changed or not

if pojo class has 20 fields, we have to write 20 if conditions
if pojo class has 5 fields, we have to write 5 if conditions

instead of writing if conditions for checking wheter data is modified or nor is there any other simplest way?

```
@Override

    public BillingTax update(BillingTax billingTax) throws DataInsufficientException, RecordNotFoundException {
        log.debug("BillingTaxServiceImpl.update()....................");
    try {

        if (billingTax == null)
            throw new DataInsufficientException("billingTax object is null");

        BillingTax billingtaxDbObject = get(billingTax.getId());

        if (billingtaxDbObject == null)
            throw new RecordNotFoundException("billingTax object is not found in database");

        if (billingTax.getTaxApplyType() != null
                && !billingTax.getTaxApplyType().equals(billingtaxDbObject.getTaxApplyType()))
            billingtaxDbObject.setTaxApplyType(billingTax.getTaxApplyType());

        if (billingTax.getCode() != null && !billingTax.getCode().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                && !billingTax.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(billingtaxDbObject.getCode()))
            billingtaxDbObject.setCode(billingTax.getCode());

        if (billingTax.getName() != null && !billingTax.getName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                && !billingTax.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(billingtaxDbObject.getName()))
            billingtaxDbObject.setName(billingTax.getName());

        if (billingTax.getDescription() != null && !billingTax.getDescription().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                && !billingTax.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase(billingtaxDbObject.getDescription()))
            billingtaxDbObject.setDescription(billingTax.getDescription());

        if (billingTax.getServiceTypeForTax() != null
                && !billingTax.getServiceTypeForTax().equals(billingtaxDbObject.getServiceTypeForTax()))
            billingtaxDbObject.setServiceTypeForTax(billingTax.getServiceTypeForTax());

        if (billingTax.getTaxValue() != null && !billingTax.getTaxValue().equals("null")
                && !billingTax.getTaxValue().equals(billingtaxDbObject.getTaxValue()))
            billingtaxDbObject.setTaxValue(billingTax.getTaxValue());

        if (billingTax.getStatus() != null && !billingTax.getStatus().equals(billingtaxDbObject.getStatus()))
            billingtaxDbObject.setStatus(billingTax.getStatus());

        if (billingTax.getOrderNo() != null && !billingTax.getOrderNo().equals("null")
                && !billingTax.getOrderNo().equals(billingtaxDbObject.getOrderNo()))
            billingtaxDbObject.setOrderNo(billingTax.getOrderNo());

        if (billingTax.getId() != null && !billingTax.getId().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(billingtaxDbObject.getId())
                && !billingTax.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(billingtaxDbObject.getId()))
            billingtaxDbObject.setId(billingTax.getId());

        if (billingTax.getStartDate()!= null && !billingTax.getStartDate().equals(billingtaxDbObject.getStartDate()))
            billingtaxDbObject.setStartDate(billingTax.getStartDate());

        if (billingTax.getEndDate()!= null && !billingTax.getEndDate().equals(billingtaxDbObject.getEndDate()))
            billingtaxDbObject.setEndDate(billingTax.getEndDate());

        billingtaxDbObject.setUpdatedDate(new Date());
        return billingTaxDAO.update(billingtaxDbObject);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("BillingTaxServiceImpl.update()....................exception:" + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to check that they're different before calling set?

Comment: to avoid to store null's in the database.

Comment: You're already checking for nulls. Why do you need to check that they're *different*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is developed by getting all the fields/properties from the pojo class and checking with wheter null data or modified data.
below is the code:

copyProperties(billingTax, billingtaxDbObject);

public void copyProperties(BillingTax source, BillingTax dest) throws Exception{

```
    if (source == null)
        throw new DataInsufficientException("billingTax object is null");

    if (dest == null)
        throw new RecordNotFoundException("billingtaxDbObject object is not found in database");

    try{
        for (Field field : source.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object sourceValue = field.get(source);
            Object destValue=field.get(dest);

            if(sourceValue!=null && sourceValue!="" && sourceValue!="null"){

                if(sourceValue instanceof String){
                    if(!sourceValue.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
                        if(!sourceValue.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(destValue.toString())){
                            field.set(dest, sourceValue);
                            System.err.println(field.getName()+" is modified:"+field.get(dest));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(!sourceValue.equals("null") && !sourceValue.equals(destValue)){
                        field.set(dest, sourceValue);
                        System.err.println(field.getName()+" is modified:"+field.get(dest));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }catch (Exception e) {
         throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Dynamic updates for hibernate if you can avoid check changes among dto and entity and update all fields that come from web. If you need check dto from web and entity you can use apache bean util to find all changed values (or use spring util if you have or reflection from java...) and update  it with dynamic updates.

see : [BeanUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html)

BeanUtils.copyProperties() // there are 3 methods.

check how it works in source code .
Create your own util method , similar to BeanUtils.copyProperties() , but with logic that you need (not null and not equal with source-entity value ).

Also use method from BeanUtils , to get PropertyDescriptor :

> public static PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors(Class clazz)
>                                                      throws BeansException

iterate over array of  PropertyDescriptor and do check that you need (set value into source with [ReflectionUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html)).

with this approach you populate only properties that are not null and changed( if you need it) into billingtaxDbObject and update it.

You can put your copy / merge method into some util class and reuse it for all place where you need copy from dto into entity with some checks.

Comment: we are using SpringBoot.but am new to spring.i would like to know how to use spring util.could you please explain with one example

Comment: By using BeanUtils, am unable to understand the source code.so i created own logic which will check not null fields and modified data from source to dest obj.

Comment: could you please explain with one pojo class with two fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CopyConverter<T> {

    private List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    private int countSuccess = 0;

    public  CopyConverter<T> convert(T source, T target, Set<String> ignoreFields){
        copyProperties(source,target,ignoreFields);
        return this;
    }

    public boolean hasError(){
        return errorMessages.isEmpty();
    }

    public List<String> getErrorMessages(){
        return errorMessages;
    }

    private boolean copyProperties(T source ,T target , Set<String> ignoreFields) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(source , "..error message...");
        Objects.requireNonNull(target , "..error message...");

        try {
            Map<String, Field> fieldNameMapping = buildFiledMap(target.getClass().
                                                       getDeclaredFields());
            ignoreFields = (ignoreFields == null ? new HashSet<>() : ignoreFields);


            for (Map.Entry<String, Field> fieldEntry : fieldNameMapping.entrySet()) {
                if (ignoreFields.contains(fieldEntry.getKey())) {
                    continue;
                }
                Field field = fieldEntry.getValue();
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object sourceValue = field.get(source);
                Object targetValue = field.get(source);

                if (isChangedAsString(sourceValue, targetValue)) {
                    field.set(target, sourceValue);
                    continue;
                }
                if (isChangedAsObject(sourceValue, targetValue)) {
                    field.set(target, sourceValue);
                }
                countSuccess++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorMessages.add(".......");
            log.info(....);
        }
        return countSuccess == 0;
    }

    private Map<String, Field> buildFiledMap(Field[] fields) {
        Map<String, Field> fieldMap = new HashMap<>(fields.length);
        //Stream.of(fields).collect(Collectors.toMap())
        for (Field field : fields) {
            fieldMap.put(field.getName(), field);
        }
        return fieldMap;
    }

    private boolean isChangedAsObject(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        return (obj1 == null && obj2 != null) || (obj1 != null && !obj1.equals(obj1));
    }


    private boolean isChangedAsString(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        if (obj1 instanceof String && obj2 instanceof String) {
            String value1 = (String) obj1;
            String value2 = (String) obj2;
            return value1 != null &&
                    !value1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null") &&//strange check
                    !value1.equalsIgnoreCase(value2);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```